# How does the community bot determine that a question needs more attention?

Tags: discussion

We very rarely see featured questions in this community so to my surprise I found a rather old question had been bumped up and was interested to see who was bumping it.

[Why is India gradually becoming a Hindu country?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/19713/why-is-india-gradually-becoming-a-hindu-country)

It then transpired that the community bot had given a bounty on this question. I am unconvinced that this question needs more attention considering it already has a highly rated answer, and there are several hundred questions on this site with a highly rated answer but not an accepted one.

That being said, how does the community bot go about making these decisions?

(I am aware the bot bumps posts every now and again, and I don't really have a problem with that, the dynamic however changes when it starts offering bounties, especially as the bot **cannot pick who to award the bounty to** and thus simply seems like a rep boost to the already highest voted answer when the bounty expires)

Comment: you might want to ask at meta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hunting around on the meta, it turns out that the community didn't actually start this bounty

[How Does the Community User Set Bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139533/how-does-the-community-user-set-bounties)

Instead a user set this bounty, but later their account was deleted - so ownership of the bounty was transferred to the community bot.

[image: screenshot of revision history]

As is apparent from revision history the bounty was actually set by former user17569